# Creating Grafana Plugin failing

Tags: npm, grafana

I am getting started building a Grafana plugin. I am working through these instructions: https://grafana.com/tutorials/build-a-panel-plugin-with-d3/#3

Running this command:

`npx @grafana/toolkit plugin:create testPlugin1`

I am confronted with this error:

`Install for @grafana/toolkit@latest failed with code 1`

Looking at the logs I see:

`error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...//registry.npmjs.org/'`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found people suggesting for a similar situation:

`npm cache clean --force`

This seemed to work! Although not exactly sure what it does.